# Derivative of vectors

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I know very little about vector calculus. What is the derivative of $\langle\alpha,\alpha\rangle$ (dot product) and $\alpha^TK\alpha$ and $\langle\alpha,y\rangle$. All these derivatives are by the variable $\alpha$. Where $K$ is a matrix and $y$ is a vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try it yourself by taking component-wise derivatives. You should get
$$\alpha\cdot\alpha \Rightarrow 2\alpha$$
and
$$\alpha^T K \alpha \Rightarrow 2K\alpha\text{ (if K is symmetric)}$$

Comment: Ok, thanks that worked.

Comment: Sorry I can't up vote your response, I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: No problem, great that it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](http://www.atmos.washington.edu/~dennis/MatrixCalculus.pdf) .pdf very helpful for these types of questions:

Comment: You can make a link by typing `[link alias that is displayed](link to item)` and filling in between the brackets appropriately.

Comment: There is no space/line break/anything between the closing $]$ and the opening $($.

Comment: @Daryl Maybe you can edit my post so that it works?